# Adding comma after MySQL query based on condition (desc or asc)

Tags: php

I am dynamically creating a query for search, based on search I need to append query with des|asc.

For example if the user click bydate I will append `order by bydate desc`, again if the user wants to search company name I append `order by companyname asc`. This is done on condition.

For example if the query is

```
select * from market
```

and if the user searches by date query becomes

```
 select * from market order by bydate desc
```

and if the user searcher by companyname query becomes

Now if the previous query contains `asc` or `desc` I need to insert comma, so the query becomes

```
select * from market order by bydate desc, companyname
```

If I don't check and insert comma query becomes

```
select * from market order by bydate desc companyname -- without comma
```

So inserting comma based on condition

```
 $query = 'select * from market order by bydate desc';

    if(  ($despos = false) && (  ( strripos($query, 'desc') !=== false && ($despos =  strripos($query, 'desc')) ) ||  ( strripos($query, 'asc') !=== false && ($despos =  strripos($query, 'asc'))  )   ) && $despost !===false   && $despos >(strlen($query)-7)  ) $query.=", ";
```

But the query shows the following error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in E:\wamp\www\sugumar\php\1.php on line 5

Comment: Add All your order by in an array then use $query = $query.implode(",", $orderBy);

Comment: Maybe it should be '==' in if condition instead of assigning '=' to $despos var

Comment: also think that if statement isn't right and it is even telling you the problem is '=' you can't have '=' with conditions '&&' and '||' to '!=' or '=='

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = "select * from market";
$orderBy = array();
```

if the user searches by date

```
array_push($orderBy, "bydate desc");
```

if the user searcher by companyname query

```
array_push($orderBy, "companyname asc");

if(count($orderBy) > 0) {
   $query = $query." order by ".implode(",", $orderBy);
}
```

Comment: thank you brilliant

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the order by params and their effective sorting order you could try something like this:

```
    $sortValues = [
    'bydate' => 'desc',
    'companyname' => 'asc'
];

$query = 'select * from market';

$count = count($sortValues);
$index = 0;
foreach($sortValues as $field => $sort){
    $index++;
    $query .= sprintf(' order by %s %s %s', $field, $sort, $index < $count ? ',' : '');
}
echo $query;
```

Result: **select * from market order by bydate desc , order by companyname asc**

Comment: thank you bro for your answer